# How to Extract Specific Values from Iterating Through Two Dataframes and Dynamically Append?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to perform a multi-step way of using values in an existing dataframe to create subset dataframes (or series) and compare those values against the existing dataframe to ultimately create one new column in the original dataframe.

The step by step process is:

- Create a dataframe that isolates the minimum date within each month (df2) based on dates in the original dataframe, df1, and this is successfully being created.
- The second step is to match where the **actual_date** (df1) matches to the the **min_date** (df2) and then take the **extract_value** (df1) and store it in df1 for all instances where the actual_date matches the **min_date**.

Some attempts I've taken but am receiving errors are:
Comparing date values between dfs:

```
df1.loc[df1['actual_date']==df2[df2['min_date']]
#Produces unexpected EOF while parsing
```

```
df['actual_date']==df2['min_date']
#Produces ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Iterating through conditions:

```
for each in range(len(df1):
    if df1[df1['actual_date']]==df2[df2['min_date']]:
        df1['exctract_value_new']=df2['extract_value']

#Produces: KeyError: "None of [DatetimeIndex....are in the [columns]"
```

I've tried searching both value and key errors and am having trouble understanding the threads regarding indexing. Specifically I am unsure how df1 and/or df2 need to be reformatted to compare date values in this manner and then extract a separate column based on when criteria matches in both dataframes.

Here is the sample data working with:

df1 (base)

| actual_date | extract_value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-22 | **22** |
| 2021-01-23 | 24 |
| 2021-01-24 | 15 |
| 2021-02-22 | 16 |
| 2021-02-05 | 34 |
| 2021-02-04 | **18** |

df2

| month | min_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-22 |
| 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-04 |
| 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-01 |

End Goal for df1

| actual_date | min_date | extract_value_new | extract_value_original |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-22 | 2021-01-22 | 22 | 22 |
| 2021-01-23 | 2021-01-22 | 22 | 24 |
| 2021-02-04 | 2021-02-04 | **18** | 18 |
| 2021-02-05 | 2021-02-04 | **18** | 34 |

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I can never remember how to do this and always end up on this page: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out `pd.merge_asof`...solution here gives me the desired table!

`merge_asof` essentially lets us join on the "closest" values in two columns.

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')

datetime_format = '%Y-%m-%d'  # format of date (needs to be a datetime to merge in pandas)
tolerance = timedelta(days=1)  # the tolerance to join dates on

# convert our dates
df1['actual_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['actual_date'], format=datetime_format)
df2['min_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['min_date'], format=datetime_format)

# sort...
df1.sort_values(by='actual_date', inplace=True)

out = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on='actual_date', right_on='min_date', tolerance=tolerance).dropna()
```

Gives me:

```
  actual_date  extract_value       month   min_date
0  2021-01-22             22  2021-01-01 2021-01-22
1  2021-01-23             24  2021-01-01 2021-01-22
3  2021-02-04             18  2021-02-01 2021-02-04
4  2021-02-05             34  2021-02-01 2021-02-04
```

Comment: Thank you for your time here -- I tried this however the target value is the "extract_value_new" column. So in your "out" the index [1] for actual_date 2021-01-23 would have extract_value_new = 22. The min_date I have working as df2 is the reference dataframe.

Comment: @bytebybyte I dont have enough context to understand that question, how is `extract_value_new` calculated? Is it not stored in `df2`? The above code will merge those two dataframes together on the nearest date which is how I interpreted your problem. You could always just rename the `extract_value` in `df2` something else and then all the values of the renamed column in the merged dataframe will be what you are looking for.

Comment: extract_value_new will be the final column we want to create and it should reflect the value of "extract_value" which is in the original df1 for the condition where the actual_date (df1) matches the min_date (df2). For example, February 4th 2022 has the extract value of 18 and matches the min_date in df2. So In df1 when we are on February 5th 2022, extract_value_NEW will also show 18. Any actual_date (df1) in february should show 18 for extract_value_new. Sorry if the context was not super clear, let me know if that helps bring any clarity?